# JsonConvert.DeserializeObject with two types of datetime format

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, json.net

I need to expect both: **dd/MM/yyyy** and **dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss**

```
var dateTimeConverter = new IsoDateTimeConverter { DateTimeFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss" };
var resultado = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyObject>(json, dateTimeConverter);
```

With this code, i received the following error message:

> System.FormatException: 'String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.'

Comment: It’s not valid JSON if it has those formats so the deserializer doesn’t need to recognize them. Preferably the system writing those should be fixed, or you’ll have to write your own deserialization code for those fields.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen json specification does not define date format, so you cannot say its invalid json.

Comment: @Evk I’ll be damned and stand corrected. They should though :P

Comment: @Evk is correct, though do note that in any public API, the *de facto* standard is ISO8601 (`yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ`).  However it's entirely reasonable that one might pass it in other locale-specific formats, especially if the field is intended to be directly rendered in a client app.  (just not in an API). ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to specify any converter at all.  By default, both of those formats will work.

```
class Foo
{
    public DateTime DateTime { get; set; }
}

// This Just Works.

string json1 = "{ \"DateTime\" : \"12/31/2017\" }";
string json2 = "{ \"DateTime\" : \"12/31/2017 23:59:59\" }";

var o1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Foo>(json1);
var o2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Foo>(json2);
```

Comment: Yep. I just set my CultureInfo and both formats works. Thx.

Comment: I had a dumb "Date" type defined.  Changing to "DateTime" fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

You can write your own JsonConverter:

```
class DataObject
{
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
}

class CustomJsonConverter : JsonConverter
{
        public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            var obj = new DataObject();

            reader.Read();
            var prop = obj.GetType().GetProperty("CreatedDate");

            reader.Read();
            var strDate = (string)reader.Value;
            DateTime date;
            if (DateTime.TryParseExact(strDate, "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out date))
                prop.SetValue(obj, date);
            if (DateTime.TryParseExact(strDate, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out date))
                prop.SetValue(obj, date);

            return obj;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could subclass IsoDateTimeConverter like this:

```
class Format1 : IsoDateTimeConverter
{
    public Format1()
    {
        DateTimeFormat = @"dd/MM/yyyy";
    }
}

class Format2 : IsoDateTimeConverter
{
    public Format2()
    {
        DateTimeFormat = @"dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss";
    }
}
```

And then you just add JsonConverter attributes to your model, like this:

```
class Entity
{
    [JsonConverter(typeof(Format1))]
    public DateTime Date1 { get; set; }
```